# Detect Apple Silicon from command line

Tags: bash, shell, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, apple-m1

How can I detect from a shell script that it is running on M1 Apple hardware?

I want to be able to run a command-line command so that I can write an `if`-statement whose body will only be executed when run on a mac with an M1 processor (and at least macOS Big Sur, naturally).

Comment: `uname -p` will probably give you the information you want, but I don't have an M1 to test.

Comment: [Tested](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-11%20at%202.15.01%20PM.png). It works.

Comment: yep that was even better. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```sh
uname -m
```

will return `arm64` as opposed to `x86_64`

```sh
if [[ $(uname -m) == 'arm64' ]]; then
  echo M1
fi
```

or, as @chepner suggested

```sh
uname -p
```

will return `arm` as opposed to `i386`

```sh
if [[ $(uname -p) == 'arm' ]]; then
  echo M1
fi
```

yet another tool is `arch`:

```sh
if [[ $(arch) == 'arm64' ]]; then
  echo M1
fi
```

Comment: Note that M1 users can run Terminal in Rosetta mode. In this case "uname -m" returns
"x86_64".

Comment: it's not just if running Terminal in Rosetta, but also if whatever process runs the script happens to be running in Rosetta too. If someone runs this in a script deployed by, say, an RMM that is running via Rosetta you'll get `x86_64`.

i think the `sysctl` approach is the best solution searching for 'Apple' in the string: `[[ $(sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string) =~ "Apple" ]]`

Comment: This doesn't work at all! If you are in VSCode Jupyter kernel it will say x86_64 even though I am on M2 Max. This `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` is the best command.

Comment: @Maziyar "doesn't work at all" is an overstatement. If your "VSCode Jupyter" is reporting `x86_64`, then that process runs through the Rosetta emulator, which is probably not what you want since both VSCode and Jupyter support Apple Silicon.

Comment: point taken, I should have said not reliable depending on where it is being executed.

Answer (score 30):

I found that `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` reported `Apple M1` even though the process was run under Rosetta.

**Update**: be prepared for `Apple M1 Pro`, `Apple M2`, `Apple M2 Max`  etc.!

Comment: This is what's needed to cleanly answer 'can I `arch -arm64 bash` my way out of here.  Hard to believe `arch` doesn't have a `-l` to list current machine available architectures.

Comment: should be the accepted answer, except for the fact that this doesn't work on linux

Comment: Be careful not to do an exact match.  My laptop returns `Apple M1 Pro`.

Comment: A MacBook Pro 16" from 2023 (with M2 Max processor) will answer `Apple M2 Max`

Answer (score 13):

When using the native shell say `/bin/bash -i` or `/bin/zsh -i`, [Klas Mellbourn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46194/klas-mellbourn) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259353/130638) works as expected.

If using a shell that was installed via an Intel/Rosetta Homebrew installation, then `uname -p` returns `i386`, and `uname -m` returns `x86_64`, as indicated by [Datasun's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8308743/datasun) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259300/detect-apple-silicon-from-command-line/68148776?noredirect=1#comment116043166_65259353).

---

To get something that works across environments (Apple Silicon Native, Rosetta Shell, Linux, Raspberry Pi 4s), I use the following from the [dorothy dotfile ecosystem](https://github.com/bevry/dorothy):

```
is-mac && test "$(get-arch)" = 'a64'
```

If you aren't using dorothy, the relevant code from dorothy is:

https://github.com/bevry/dorothy/blob/1c747c0fa6bb3e6c18cdc9bae17ab66c0603d788/commands/is-mac

```
test "$(uname -s)" = "Darwin"
```

https://github.com/bevry/dorothy/blob/1c747c0fa6bb3e6c18cdc9bae17ab66c0603d788/commands/get-arch

```
arch="$(uname -m)"  # -i is only linux, -m is linux and apple
if [[ "$arch" = x86_64* ]]; then
    if [[ "$(uname -a)" = *ARM64* ]]; then
        echo 'a64'
    else
        echo 'x64'
    fi
elif [[ "$arch" = i*86 ]]; then
    echo 'x32'
elif [[ "$arch" = arm* ]]; then
    echo 'a32'
elif test "$arch" = aarch64; then
    echo 'a64'
else
    exit 1
fi
```

---

[Jatin Mehrotra's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13126651/jatin-mehrotra) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67996219/130638) on [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67996157/130638) gives details on how to get the specific CPU instead of the architecture. Using `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` outputs `Apple M1` on my M1 Mac Mini, however outputs the following on a Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu Server:

```
> sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
Command 'sysctl' is available in the following places
 * /sbin/sysctl
 * /usr/sbin/sysctl
The command could not be located because '/sbin:/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
sysctl: command not found

> sudo sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/machdep/cpu/brand_string: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If `uname -m` returns `x86_64` I think you are probably running your terminal through Rosetta. Have you checked `Open using Rosetta` in the `Get Info`  dialog for the terminal program?

Comment: `Open using Rosetta` is unchecked: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrhxgkxtmi2wv74/CleanShot%202021-06-28%20at%2006.24.52%402x.png?dl=0

If I run a new command `/bin/bash -i` and then run `uname -m` then it returns `arm64` and `uname -p` returns `arm`. So is caused by my default shell, which is installed by homebrew, being run through rosetta.

Thanks for helping me track this down. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/arch
is all you need. Why complicate things when there's already a program to do this for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259353/619961 already provides this information. Why add it again?