# How do I detect a M1 mac processor in MATLAB?

Tags: macos, matlab

Is there a way of detecting a M1 mac in MATLAB? MATLAB has `ismac` but that presumably won't differentiate between processor types.

Comment: Detecting a M1 mac versus what? See the `computer` and `ismac` functions

Comment: Or maybe the `cpuInfoMac` subfunction [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33155-cpu-info) (I haven't tested it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New Answer: Tested on M1 Mac**

My impression is that MATLAB is running through Rosetta 2, which means that the result of `uname -m` is actually `x86_64`, which does not help guard against calls to Intel targeting mex code.

Instead we'll ask for the kernel version and try to find ARM64

```
if ismac()
    [~,result] = system('uname -v');
    is_m1_mac = any(strfind(result,'ARM64'));
else
    is_m1_mac = false;
end
```

Note `result` above is on my computer : `Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:37 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000`

**Old Answer: Not correct**

To detect the processor one can call to the system command line:
[Detect Apple Silicon from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259300/detect-apple-silicon-from-command-line)

**Note, this has not been tested on a m1 mac ...**

```
if ismac()
    [~,result] = system('uname -m');
    is_m1_mac = strcmp(strtrim(result),'arm64');
else
    is_m1_mac = false;
end
```

Note, this would help if you are running an older version of MATLAB, as MATLAB doesn't officially support M1 macs until 2020b update 3 ...
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/641925-is-matlab-supported-on-apple-silicon-macs

However, it is not clear to me that this would eventually detect execution of MATLAB natively vs via ROSETTA (when a native option actually exists).

Answer (score 0):

Tested on M2 pro with R2022b (ARM beta):

```
system('uname -m')
arm64

ans =

     0
```

and

```
if ismac()
    [~,result] = system('uname -m');
    is_m1_mac = strcmp(strtrim(result),'arm64');
else
    is_m1_mac = false;
end

>> is_m1_mac

is_m1_mac =

  logical

   1
```