# Detect Apple silicon GPU core count

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, metal

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259300/detect-apple-silicon-from-command-line), I am interested in detecting the exact GPU inside a Mac equipped with Apple silicon.

I am interested in knowing the exact GPU core count.

```bash
sysctl -a | grep gpu
```

or

```bash
sysctl -a | grep core
```

does not seem to provide anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect GPU core count on **Apple Silicon** architecture you can use this command:

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ioreg` like this:

```
 ioreg -l | grep gpu-core-count
```

You can also look up an object with class that's named something like `AGXAcceleratorG13X` and see all of its properties, `gpu-core-count` will also be there.

Comment: PSA: This is the only command that works in Recovery Mode on recent installs